# Building FIFO data structure in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have created FIFO data structure with only necessary methods. Facing an issue while using `.pop()` method.

It is successfully removing the value from queue, but not returning the right value.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None


class Queue(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.size = 0

    def append(self, item):
        if self.first == None:
            node = Node(item)
            self.first = node
        else:
            self.next = Node(item)

        self.size+=1

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception('Empty queue')

        item = self.first.item
        if self.next != None:
            self.first = self.next
        self.size-=1
        return item

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size == 0
```

**Input & Ouput:**

```
>>> a = Queue()
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a.append(2)
>>> a.append(3)
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a.pop()
1
>>> a.pop()
4
>>> a.pop()
4
>>> a.pop()
4
>>> a.pop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    a.pop()
  File "D:/PERSONAL DATA/python/Online Compitions/Hackerrank/morgan_and_string.py", line 28, in pop
    raise Exception('Empty queue')
Exception: Empty queue
```

Can anyone please help to find where the issue is?

Comment: Can you share the output that you are receiving?

Comment: You're mixing up `Queue` and `Node` - for example, you're setting `self.next` in `append()` and `pop()` of `Queue`, but it's `Node` that has a `next`, `Queue` does not. Also, using `pop` for a queue is very confusing, it's a verb typically applied to a stack.

Comment: @Grismar `Queue` is a subclass of `Node`.

Comment: @Barmar - ah, you're right, which further confuses the issue though, since a 'queue' is very much not a 'node'

Comment: @Grismar Sorry, please explain it more clearly. I didn't understand.

Comment: Your `append` code is wrong. You need to iterate to the end of the chain before attaching then next node.

Comment: @Grismar I want to refer current element to the `.next` of current Node().

Comment: @MarkMeyer Can you please check above comment. Am I not doing what I said in code?

Comment: If this is not an exercise you could use the `deque`  class from the standard `collections` module.

Comment: Use `deque` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679914/how-does-deque-work-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you make `Queue` inherit from `Node`, but it appears that 'nodes' are really the elements in the queue, while the queue is managing the whole thing. Also, you named the methods 'pop' and 'push', but for a queue, you typically talk about reading and writing, since popping and pushing is what you do to a stack.

With that in mind, the code below has various fixes to your code, but the same overall structure and I think it works as you expect:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.size = 0

    def write(self, item):
        node = Node(item)

        if self.first is None:
            self.first = node

        if self.last is None:
            self.last = node
        else:
            self.last.next = node
            self.last = node

        self.size += 1

    def read(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception('Empty queue')

        item = self.first.item

        self.first = self.first.next
        if self.first is None:
            self.last = None

        self.size -= 1
        return item

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size == 0
```

A few remarks on key differences:

- Queue no longer inherits from Node
- `.next` is used on instances of Node, so for example `self.first.next`
- I've added a `.last` since you want access to both the start and the end of a queue

Here's some code to test it:

```
q = Queue()
q.write('a')
q.write('b')
print(q.read())
q.write('c')
print(q.read())
print(q.read())

# read from empty queue
print(q.read())
```

It works with the above, it didn't work with some of the other answers, but perhaps I'm missing how they expect the code to be used.

Output:

```
a
b
c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/project/python/sandbox/q.py", line 53, in <module>
    print(q.read())
  File "C:/dev/project/python/sandbox/q.py", line 29, in read
    raise Exception('Empty queue')
Exception: Empty queue
```

Comment: I don't want `.last` element of my queue. Can you implement without it?

Comment: If you pay me by the hour - sure! You can do what @vishakhaLall showed, `while(start.next):  start = start.next  start.next = Node(item)`, that's trading some computation for the extra variable.

Comment: Haha, nice. I haven't mentioned *since you want access to both the start and the end of a queue*. Thanks for details provided in answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you append, you should be setting the `next` element of the last node, not the first node. This can be made easier by having both `first` and `last` attributes in the class (otherwise you need a loop to find the last node).

`pop()` should always set `self.first` to the next node, even if it's `None`.

```
class Queue():

    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.size = 0
        self.last = None

    def append(self, item):
        node = Node(item)
        if self.first is None:
            self.first = node
            self.last = node
        else:
            self.last.next = node
            self.last = self.last.next

        self.size+=1

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception('Empty queue')

        item = self.first.item
        self.first = self.first.next
        if self.first is None:
            self.last = None
        self.size-=1
        return item

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size == 0
```

There's also no need for `Queue` to be a subclass of `Node`, it never uses anything it inherits.

Comment: Can we implement this without `.last`?

Comment: I fixed it. `self.next` should be `self.first.next`.

Comment: If you do it without `.last` you have to loop, like in @VishakhaLall's answer.

Comment: Thanks. It means without using loop, if i want to append then .last must required?

Comment: You want to append to the end of the queue, you have to find the last node somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected code with minimum changes to the original code

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None


class Queue(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.size = 0

    def append(self, item):
        if self.first == None:
            node = Node(item)
            self.first = node
        else:
            start = self.first
            while(start.next):
                start = start.next
            start.next = Node(item)

        self.size+=1

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception('Empty queue')

        item = self.first.item
        if self.first.next != None:
            self.first = self.first.next
        self.size-=1
        return item

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size == 0
```

It's important to note that item and next are attributes of the Node class while first and size are those of the Queue class.